# Assign unique contract number to PDF using Acrobat Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, xml-rpc, acrobat

Interesting problem: I want our sales staff of 3 to use the same master PDF (strictly on our own server from within our intranet) to create a unique document set for each client of our business, which document set includes a contract.

A state regulator randomly audits our supply of contract forms, and assesses a fee for each missing contract, so the contracts must be sequentially numbered with no apparent gaps.  I want the "Finalize Contract" button in my PDF to run an Acrobat JavaScript that posts a request to a webservice written in PHP, which webservice should connect to a MySQL table, autoincrements the number in in question in the table, and return the value to the Acrobat JavaScript for assignment to the proper field.

I have done enough research to know what I want to do. I am enough of a coding virgin to not know the nuts and bolts of how to do it. I can take PMs on this for an open dialogue off the board if you wish, just need to get it done.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have a look at JQuery and it's Ajax function for the part of retrieving PHP data from JavaScript: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Regarding the PHP part, you want to connect to a database and fetch and update some information. This might help: http://de.php.net/manual/de/function.mysql-query.php